# AWS SNS Queing Behaviour

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

We have a logging mechanism through which we broadcast exception logs using Amazon Simple Notification Service.

On working on Amazon Simple Notification Service I figured out that Amazon Simple Notification Service queuing notification(s) which have to published.
How can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

A little more details would be needed on the behaviour you're seeing.
How and where are you measuring this behaviour, on the client Publishing the messages to SNS or on the destination endpoints receiving the notifications?

What is the issue you are seeing? If it is ordering, ordering is not guaranteed when using SNS:
https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/

> The Amazon SNS service will attempt to deliver messages from the
>   publisher in the order they were published into the topic. However,
>   network issues could potentially result in out-of-order messages at
>   the subscriber end.